# Rails production environment safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've switched over to being primarily a Rails developer recently. One thing that I have not figured out is how to protect developers from making careless mistakes while the application is in production mode on a local machine. Because I am using Heroku and MongoLab, I can access my production environment resources from my local machine. This is really great when I need to debug an issue happening in the production environment using my local machine. However this makes it incredibly easy for someone on the team to forget they are currently running their local server in production mode and mistakenly screw something up - for example delete all records within the database.

Does anyone have some best practices on how to prevent careless mistakes from happening?

Comment: Have you considered running the application in the development environment while debugging locally?

Comment: Generally, Rails' `development` environment is meant to be used locally. Production should, in theory, be accessible, but people *really* shouldn't be mucking around up there with live data. This is also why [dev/prod parity](http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) is a very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best practice" for doing this. What you are looking for is a best practice for using a *worst* practice.  There is absolutely no way your development machine should ever be able to able to talk to your production database.

Your production credentials shouldn't be included in your version control system, and so nobody should even be available to access the production database from their development machines.

If you really want to test in production, configure a "production" database locally, on your workstation, away from your real production server, and copy some production data into it.

Answer (score 1):

`rails c production --sandbox`

*Always*, unless you are going in there with the purpose of managing records. The `--sandbox` flag wraps the entire console session in a database transaction and rolls back any database changes you make on exit.

But as the others have said, if you find yourself needing to test stuff in production, then what you *really* need to do is setup your development environment to more closely mimic your production environment. I know that's a little more difficult on a cloud service like Heroku, but you can get pretty darn close.

Comment: Sandbox doesn't help with a non transactional db such as mongo